Acrobar Reader dragdrop Extracting pages in Windows Explorer. Using In VB NET
When I want to extract pages from a PDF file, I simply highlight the pages I want in the Thumbnails menu in Acrobat Reader and drag them to the location I want in Explorer. The cursor shows a "Copy" icon, I release and the selected pages are exported to a file named "Untitled Extracted Pages.pdf". I want to drag selected pages onto a Button in a VB.Net form and use the DragDrop event handler to receive a file with these selected pages. How to process this?
Thanks.
I tried to determine DragEventArgs.Data But I have _ComObject and I dont know what to do with this...
